# Dynamics AX 2009 Workflow Deadlock

Tags: dynamics-ax-2009

Randomly some workflow processes are in error with the message:

> Can not select a record in Table messages workflow (WorkflowMessageTable). Message ID workflow: {00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}, {00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}.
>   Deadlock. One or more users have locked simultaneously the entire table or part of it.

What tools can I use to determine the cause of the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I Finally found the problem.

The message is made by internal loop of workflow, but the main problem is that the workflow approval task lose the link with display item of the form that manage element of workflow.